# Mask generation for CAN hardware receive buffers

Tags: java, embedded, bit-manipulation, microcontroller, can-bus

I am working with CAN (Controller Area Network), and I am trying to come up with an algorithm that generates the masks and the IDs of the hardware buffer slots.

For example:

I have two integer arrays that contain the IDs that I want to be received by my microcontroller, and the IDs that I want to be ignored by my microcontroller.

I am now going from a minimum mask of 0 and going to the max value depending on the number of bits on which the ID is represented (11 bits).

So I am going from 0 to 7FF and try to find a mask that can contain one or more messages from the list of IDs that I want to accept, and none of the IDs that I do not want to accept.

Up to 7FF is OK, this algorithm can be used. Granted it's not the best, but it's served its purpose. But I am trying to find something more efficient, and I also want to apply this to 29 bits. Going from 0 to 7FFFFFFF takes a really long time.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

PS: The algorithm is supposed to be written in Java.

Comment: So, what have you tried? Can you post code / examples of what you're trying to do? Have you RTFM on bitmasks / bitwise logic operators?

Comment: @John: OP wrote what he tried: he simply iterated through all numbers from 0 to max. And if that worked, he obviously knows how to do bitwise operations. The question was how to do it more efficiently.

Comment: @Groo - it wasn't obvious to me that he was describing a solid algorithm, as opposed to posting some (pseudo)code / example.

Comment: I truly empathize with your problem.  The acceptance filters on most modern CAN hardware are a real PITA and just unuseable with many protocols.

Comment: @Martin: I had no clue this was a common problem. Are bitwise masks really sufficient for this purpose?

Comment: Ok, I just searched the web a bit, and apparently CAN acceptance filters are usually specified for *ranges* of messages, meaning that the "accept list" may be rather lengthy. Is that true? If you have a specific (more realistic) example, there might be a better solution.

Comment: My problem is that a legacy protocol defines address bit-masks to both address CAN endpoints and also, (not my design!), to define a message-type and 'channel' that are used inside the endpoint. This means that, to extract every message destined for one endpoint, the number ranges of messages are impossibly large - far exceeding the capacity of the hardware general acceptance filters :((((

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need all possible solutions, but only a list of masks which would match at least one item from the "accept list" and match no items from the "ignore list", then you can most likely improve your current algorithm by writing a simple `O(n*m)` algorithm (where `n` and `m` are list lengths).

If your lists are relatively short, this would work much faster than iterating from 0 to 2<sup>29</sup>. Additionally, if these lists will never change and you only need to do this once, then this is probably your best choice.

A pseudoalgorithm would be something like:

```
for each candidate in the "accept list"
   do a bitwise AND with all items in the "ignore list"
   if there is a match then (break as soon as you find a match)
       this candidate cannot be matched
   else
       this candidate is one of the solutions
```

This will, of course, return masks which can match only a single item. If you want the smallest set of masks, you could postprocess the candidate list and discard masks which are already contained in other masks (that's additional `O(n*n)`).

If you have a large number of items in your "ignore list", and need to lookup the list often, it would make more sense to put your ignored items in a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (or a [radix trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree), or a [DAWG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph), these are more or less the same thing).

For each candidate, you would then go bit by bit through the trie and quickly discard items which have a `1` bit in place of a `0` bit in your mask. This would give something like `O(n+m)` complexity (`O(m)` to build the trie, `O(1*n)` to lookup the trie for each item in the accept list):

```
(presuming you have built a trie from "ignore list" items)
for each candidate in the "accept list"
    get a binary representation of the candidate
    perform a dfs of the trie 
        if node at level k is 1 and candidate bit at position k is 0
        then 
            discard that subtree
        else
            continue searching until the last leaf
```

This all depends on the actual length of your lists, and the frequency at which you need to perform this search. If you have two lists of 10000 items each, and you only need to do this once, I would opt for the first algorithm, it would probably take no more than a couple of seconds to finish (exact running time will depend on the number of early matches in the ignore list).